# Android Studio doesn't display layout preview in a certain layout file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, layout

[image: Layout preview is invisible]

[image: Error details]

Even Though my xml code has no errors, the preview layout doesn't work.
It's weird, because I didn't make any change to the code and all of a sudden, the layout preview doesn't work.
In my other xml files, the layout preview works.

What I've been tried to do (without success):

1. Rebuilding the project.
2. Refreshing the layout.
3. Changing the API version of the preview device.
4. Changing the preview device Model.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try File -> Invalidate Caches and restart. Also, what are the details in the error about inflating the preview?

Comment: It has been solved! it turns out that the problem was that I was having an TextView's attribute in my xml file that was something like: android:text="" (Empty string).

Comment: click on blue button at top-left corner in preview screen, select 'force refresh layout'